# Time zone in date?

Tags: linux, date, timezone, localtime

From where does the [`date`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) command in Linux get the time zone information?

I cannot see the `/etc/localtime` file and the `/usr/share/zoneinfo` directory on my system. Still, when I execute the `date` command, I get the following output:

> Thu Dec  9 16:28:18 UTC 2010

Kindly tell me: From where does the command get the time zone information?

Comment: Is the variable $TZ set in your environment?

Comment: No it is not set. When i do `echo $TZ` it gives nothing!!

Comment: Does /etc/TZ exist on your system?

Comment: `/etc/TZ` file is there. But i think the system does not take the time from that file. Because if i modify this file to some other timezone and then reboot, It should show the new timezone. But that does not happen. In my case /etc/TZ is a symbolic link to /etc/cmm/TZ. /etc/cmm/TZ is the file created by my application as part of the root file system.

Comment: No /etc/timezone does not exist

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_universal_time) is how standard Unix systems store the date/time in the real time clock. You have to jump through hoops using funny programs (see the `hwclock(8)` manpage) if you dual-boot to Windows, which prefers the *local* time to be stored in the CMOS real time clock.

So the `date(1)` program is simply showing you the results of "I have no configured time zone":

```
# date -u
Thu Dec  9 10:40:54 UTC 2010
# TZ=UTC date
Thu Dec  9 10:40:57 UTC 2010
# TZ=PST8PDT date
Thu Dec  9 02:41:02 PST 2010
#
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Timezone-in-Linux

> On mobile phones and other small devices that run Linux, the time zone
>   is stored differently. It is written in /etc/TZ, in the format that is
>   described, for instance, in [[4]](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19057-01/nscp.cal.svr.35/816-5523-10/appf.htm) . Edit this file manually or use
>   echo (for instance, echo GMT0BST > /etc/TZ to set the the timezone of
>   the United Kingdom).

From http://www.radisys.com/files/support_downloads/03245-02_MPCMM0001_MPCMM0002_CMM_Software_TPS.pdf

> The CMM determines the offset to local timezone maintained in file
>   /etc/cmm/TZ and automatically updates the time.