# TZ Variable, custom file

Tags: linux, timezone, gnu

I have an embedded system where we wish to create custom daylight savings times.

I can achieve this by setting the TZ environment variable, for example: `export TZ=IST-2IDT,M3.4.4/26,M10.5.0`.

We have several daemons running (eg. daemonA, daemonB, etc.), and if one of those exports `TZ` then the other daemons won't be able to see it.  So that's an issue.  A possible work around might be to use a file instead of an environment variable so that 'everyone' can see it.

The GNU C Library manual says the following:

`:characters
Each operating system interprets this format differently; in the  GNU C Library, characters is the name of a file which describes the time zone.`

When I `export TZ=:/etc/TZ`, and then `echo IST-2IDT,M3.4.4/26,M10.5.0 > /etc/TZ`, it doesn't work.  I see this, when I issue the `date` command:

`Mon Aug 15 04:19:36 /etc/TZ 2016`

Is anybody able to give me any clues?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files such as /etc/TZ depend on the type of system (call them *nonstandard* as such, though standardization is poor in this area).  The usual way timezone is configured is via the /etc/localtime files. Normally these are generated from rule (text) files by the [timezone compiler](http://linux.die.net/man/8/zic). It is in the [tzfile](http://linux.die.net/man/5/tzfile) manual page for instance.

The [timezone-in-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396575/timezone-in-date) is a good place to start reading further - since it mentions a few possibilities regarding /etc/TZ.  If /etc/TZ is what works for your system, the accepted answer there points to this [Oracle page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19057-01/nscp.cal.svr.35/816-5523-10/appf.htm), which appears to document the format.

Comment: Hi Thomas.  I'm using glibc. I've done a little research and it seems glibc/eglibc don't use /etc/TZ, but instead use /etc/localtime just like you said.  The /etc/localtime way works, but does not suit my requirements because I need to be able to create custom timezones at runtime, when using the embedded board.  The TZ environment variable achieves this but other daemons cannot see it (as mentioned in the original post).

Comment: Whether you set an environment variable or update /etc/localtime, you would have to restart the other daemons to make them use the new timezone settings.

Comment: You may have seen this, of course: http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2012-October/060338.html