# Create TZ-File out of TZ-String

Tags: linux, unix, timezone, timezone-offset

I want to create a [TF-File](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tzfile.5.html) for storing Unix Time Zone informations out of a TZ-String as define in [POSIX 1003.1 section 8.3](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/wclock/help/wclo_tzsyntax.html).
It seems that timezone compiler [zic](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/zic.8.html) does not cover this.

For a test I created a file "MYZ.txt" compatible to "zic" dealing with a phantasie time zone "MYZ=My Zone" with UTC offset +0:30 (or +1:30 in summer):

```
#TZ=MYZ-0:30MYSZ,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3
Rule MYsummer min max - Mar lastSun 2:00w 1:00 MYSZ
Rule MYsummer min max - Oct lastSun 3:00w 0    MYZ
Zone MYZ 0:30 MYsummer %s
```

The commented first line has the same information as the two rules and Zone information below.
`zic MYZ.txt -d /tmp` does what I want and stores the time zone information into "/tmp/MYZ".

What I like to use is something like calling

```
export TZ=MYZ-0:30MYSZ,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3
zic -d /tmp
```

and having the same time zone information in "/tmp/MYZ" like above.

Of corse I could implement a tool creating "MYZ.txt" out of the TZ environment variable.
But I guess somthing similar is avaible within the UNIX/Linux standard tools.

This may be realted to [TZ Variable, custom file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491719/tz-variable-custom-file) .

Thanks for any help,
Tom